# Upserting and maintaing postgres table using Apache Airflow

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, airflow, etl, mwaa

Working on an ETL process that requires me to pull data from one postgres table and update data to another Postgres table in a seperate environment (same columns names). Currently, I am running the python job in a windows EC2 instance, and I am using **[pangres](https://github.com/ThibTrip/pangres)** upsert library to update existing rows and insert new rows.

However, my organization wants me to move the python ETL script in Managed Apache Airflow on AWS.

I have been learning DAGs and most of the tutorials and articles are about querying data from postgres table using hooks or operators.

However, I am looking to understand how to update existing table A incrementally (i.e. upsert) using new records from table B (and ignore/overwrite existing matching rows).

Any chunk of code (DAG) that explains how to perform this simple task would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In Apache Airflow, operations are done using operators. You can package any Python code into an operator, but your best bet is always to use a pre-existing open source operator if one already exists. There is an operator for Postgres (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-postgres/stable/operators/postgres_operator_howto_guide.html).

It will be hard to provide a complete example of what you should write for your situation, but it sounds to be like the best approach for you to take here is to take any SQL present in your Python ETL script and use it with the Postgres operator. The documentation I linked should be a good example.

They demonstrate inserting data, reading data, and even creating a table as a pre-requisite step. Just like how in a Python script, lines execute one at a time, in a DAG, operators execute in a particular order, depending on how they're wired up, like in their example:

```py
create_pet_table >> populate_pet_table >> get_all_pets >> get_birth_date
```

In their example, populating the pet table won't happen until the create pet table step succeeds, etc.

Since your use case is about copying new data from one table to another, a few tips I can give you:

- Use a scheduled DAG to copy the data over in batches. Airflow isn't meant to be used a streaming system for many small pieces of data.
- Use the "logical date" of the DAG run (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/dag-run.html) in your DAG to know the interval of data that run should process. This works well for your requirement that only new data should be copied over during each run. It will also give you repeatable runs in case you need to fix code, then re-run each run (one batch a time) after pushing your fix.

Comment: The article you have mentioned is great however, it doesn't give specific examples of upsert new records. I see there is an example of inserting rows in there but that is now what I am looking for, per se. The final solution I am looking for is where ideally the DAG pulls the last three months of data from table A and append them into table B without having duplicates.

Comment: Edited my answer to give you a few tips for your use case.

Comment: Actually, I think I misunderstood what you're trying to do. When you use the word "upsert", it sounds like your goal is to process data at least once. You want to process it when it's created (by copying it from table A to table B) and then also process it whenever it's updated in table A (by copying it again to table B, overwriting any row with its primary key if one exists). Can you add more detail to your question clarifying what your goal is? And an example of what data you'd like in tables A and B at certain points in time with an example schedule would help.

Comment: This workflow examples the following link explains the use case pretty well. https://github.com/ThibTrip/pangres/wiki/Upsert

Comment: Upsert is an operation you can do on a table. If you need to know how to do Postgres operations on a table, the operator is all you need to read up on. You'll be using pure Postgres SQL (not the pangres library), and the Postgres operator supports all Postgres SQL. You just need to translate what pangres is doing to Postgres SQL. If you're talking about some sort of pattern with more than one table, you'll have to expand on what you're trying to do with those tables. There are many ways to copy data from one to another.

Comment: Makes sense. For my purpose, I am looking to simply insert rows from temp pandas dataframe to an existing postgres tables. If the primary key in dataframe and posgres table has conflict (due to duplicate primary key), at that point, update the rows in postgres table. 

Pangres makes this extremely easy in an automated fashion, especially since I am maintaining 40+ backup tables. One of the ways I have read is to make make your dataframe into a temporary table in postgres and then merge it with the final table, the problem with that is defining schema for 40+ temp tables manually…